# Why are there different outcomes with Terminal and Sublime, while Python scripts are totally the same?

Tags: python, statistics, sublimetext, correlation

I have a csv file with two columns of data, and was trying to calculate their Spearman's Correlation Coefficient with Python. Here are my codes:

```
file = open('last_2.csv')
records = file.readlines()
items = []
groups = []
readership = []
for each in records:
    items = each.strip().split(',')
    readership.append(items[0])
    groups.append(items[1])

import scipy.stats
cc = scipy.stats.spearmanr(readership,groups)
print (cc)
```

While running them in Terminal (I'm using mac), it returns (0.3745301276716122, 0.0) as result; and while building them with Sublime, it returns (0.18597808700272841, 0.0). They are not the same. Why did this happen, and which is the correct result?

Comment: Different working directories, probably. You are reading different files. That or you are importing different versions of the `scipy` library. Verify with `os.getcwd()` (and use absolute paths instead of a relative path), and with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.

Comment: Example of your last_2.csv file

Comment: Thanks to @MartijnPieters , my scipy version is "0.14.1rc1" by Terminal, and "0.11.0" by Sublime. Now I'm wondering how the difference in version affects results? Anyway the algorithms for Spearman's correlation calculation are the same, right?

Comment: @Huiqin: there may be a bug in the older version. You are using different Python binaries in your terminal and your Sublime. See http://robinwragg.tumblr.com/post/55364315373/how-to-specify-which-python-version-sublime-text-2 on how to change the Python version used.